# Serverless triggered with SQS not send the output to configured destination

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, serverless-architecture

I am using a serverless framework, with a triggering function `hello` with SQS and this is done correctly with the following config.

```
functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
    # Provide the ARN of your queue
      - sqs: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:abc:sqs_input
```

after adding the destination to the config

```
destinations:
  onSuccess: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:abc:sqs_output
  onFailure: arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:abc:sqs_output
```

it works fine only if I call it from AWS CLI with adding `--invocation-type Event` parameter

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name testdestination-dev-hello --invocation-type Event response.json
```

but in my case, the input will be triggered by input SQS and I can not add the `--invocation-type Event` option, so How can I always active the SQS destination?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, Lambda destinations only work with asynchronous Lambda invocations. SQS invokes Lambda synchronously, so Lambda destinations do not work/apply here.

See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/

You are going to have to post a message to SQS programmatically within your Lambda in this case.